# How can I change the cursor in windows globally?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.8

I'm trying to make a program that allows you to pick a point on the screen.  I click a button then hide my form, then show a very tiny form (to allow for the use of tooltips).  I then show a tooltip by the mouse until the user left-clicks then show the form again.  My issue is I can't seem to make the mouse show a specific mouse pointer (crosshairs) to target a location.

I have tried to use the following which is suggested all over the web with no joy...

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Cross;
```

Comment: The window the cursor is over gets to define the cursor. Unless your program runs as admin, it won't be able to capture mouse input to all other programs. Best to use a full screen transparent window.

Comment: @Mikael does it answer my question?  I think so.  Am I happy about it?  100% not.  This seems really crazy to have to jump through these type hoops in the frameworks we work in these days.  Geez.  Thanks for pointing that question out, I swear I spent quite some time trying to find the answer myself.

Comment: The *other way* (already previously mentioned): use a small boderless Form (e.g., 32x32), no Caption (so it won't be resized), set its BackColor to Red and the same its TransparencyKey; set the Form's Cursor to Cursor.Cross; show it on screen. You'll see only the Form's Cursor. You can move it around using a Timer or hooking the Mouse movements. -- Or use Color.Magenta or Color.LimeGreen and draw the Cursor in the OnPaint override (`Cursors.Cross.Draw(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle);`). Now, the Form is a click-through Window, the Cursor is still visible, but you can interact with other Windows.